# Pythonic Way of Lexicographically Sorting Keys of an OrderedDict On Insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary, lexicographic

I have the following class that keeps track of an `OrderedDict`:

```
class LexDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_map = OrderedDict() # maps string which is case-sensitive to int

    def set(self,id,seqNo):
        self.m_map[id] = seqNo

    def get(self,id): # seqNo returned
        return self.m_map[id] if self.has(id) else 0

    def has(self,id): # bool value
        return ( id in self.m_map.keys() )

    def to_str(self):
        stream = ""
        for key,value in self.m_map.items():
            stream = stream + key + ":" + str(value) + " "
        return stream.rstrip()
```

My goal is to change the set() method to make it lexicographic at all times so that no matter when to_str() is called, it will be in lexicographic order. We can safely assume no mapping in this dictionary will be removed. This will be used in a network situation so efficiency is key and sorting the entire list rather than moving it in the correct spot would hurt performance.

An example of how this could be used.

```
a = LexDict()

a.set("/Justin",1) # the id will have "/"s (maybe even many) in it, we can image them without "/"s for sorting

a.set("/James",600)

a.set("/Austin",-123)
print( a.to_str() )
```

Output `/Austin:-123 /James:600 /Justin:1`

Comment: What exactly is your question? Also, rather than inventing a custom API, why not make it a [`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) so you can actually use it as a dictionary replacement?

Comment: An ordered dict only remembers insertion order. You would have to keep track of lexical order e.g. in a separate list. So you could create a list that holds the IDs in lexical order. At every insertion you find the insertion point (e.g. by binary tree search) and add the ID at the corresponding list position.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused. It sounds like you are referring to the OrderedDict class from the sortedcollections module; that module also contains what you are looking for, namely a SortedDict. In general, the sortedcollections module contains many containers for efficiently using large lists and dictionaries. For example, look up time in a SortedDict is O(log(n)) instead of O(n) for normal python dict().

```
from sortedcollections import SortedDict

D = SortedDict([("/James",600),("/Justin",1),("/Austin",-123)])
print(D)
```

In general, SortedDict and SortedList can hold millions of values, but instantly look up values.

Comment: I think, OP is referring to `OrderedDict` from `collections` but +1 for `SortedDict`, didn't know about that one and now my comment under OP sounds stupid.

Comment: @Dschoni I thought that OrderedDict from collections was integrated to python's builtin dict(). That is, all dict()'s are already OrderedDicts. So, the one from collections is no longer needed.